# "CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[23000]:" Example from book

Tags: php, yii, mysql-error-1452

Good day!
Faced with such a problem, when creating Issue (http://test.com/book/ima/index.php?ssue/create&pid=1) get this error:

```
CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`trackstar`.`tbl_issue`, CONSTRAINT `fk_issue_owner` FOREIGN KEY (`owner_id`) REFERENCES `tbl_user` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE). The SQL statement executed was: INSERT INTO `tbl_issue` (`project_id`, `name`, `description`, `type_id`, `status_id`, `owner_id`, `requester_id`, `create_time`, `create_user_id`, `update_time`, `update_user_id`) VALUES (:yp0, :yp1, :yp2, :yp3, :yp4, :yp5, :yp6, :yp7, :yp8, :yp9, :yp10)

/var/www/yii/framework/db/CDbCommand.php(357)

345         {
...
```

I tried to do as here:
http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/11953-cdbcommand-failed-to-execute-the-sql-statement-sqlstate23000-integrity-constraint-violation/

```
 public function rules()
{
    // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
    // will receive user inputs.
    return array(
        array('name, project_id', 'required'),
        .....
        ........
    );
}
```

It did not work.
Help solve the problem, I want to study further, but because of it I can not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [link](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/11953-cdbcommand-failed-to-execute-the-sql-statement-sqlstate23000-integrity-constraint-violation/) and error you have given, there was constraint violation could be due to:

```
The user_id attempting to be inserted is not associated with a valid tbl_user.id value in the tbl_user table.
```

The error message was so obviously. You tried to insert into `tbl_issue` one record which contains the foreign key `user_id` does not exist on `tbl_user`.

Comment: Mark my above answer as accepted if it resolved your problem. Glad to help.